# PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am running the following SP but getting the error c1.pyid is invalid identifier. I am trying to use two different query results from one cursor. If there is any other way of using IF-else clause in a cursor, i am open to that too.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE
  PROCEDURE FIX_DOCUMENT_RECORDS ( i_flag in varchar)
AS
Op_ID      VARCHAR(8);
Op_Name    VARCHAR(32);
  skill      VARCHAR(32);
temp_count VARCHAR(8);
temp_status VARCHAR(8):='Submitted';
QRYSTR VARCHAR2(400);
TYPE REF_CUR IS REF CURSOR;
 c1 REF_CUR;

BEGIN
 IF (i_flag='1') THEN
 QRYSTR:='SELECT *
FROM dims_doc_master
WHERE concat_prod_id      IS NULL
OR documenttypeid      IS NULL
AND (pystatuswork       = temp_status);';
ELSE
QRYSTR:='SELECT *
FROM dims_doc_master
WHERE (documentimageid IS NULL
AND p8id               IS NULL)
   AND (pystatuswork       = temp_status);';
END IF;   

 open c1 FOR QRYSTR;
LOOP
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('loop begin');
  UPDATE DIMS_DOC_MASTER
  SET pystatuswork  ='Cancelled',
    documentstatus  ='Cancelled',
    cancellationdate='31-JAN-14',
    cancelledbysid  = c1.pxcreateoperator,
    cancelreason    ='Cancelled due to corruption.'
  WHERE pyid        =c1.pyid;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('After updation'||c1.pyid );
  --Begin PC_DOCUMENT UPDATION
  UPDATE PC_DOCUMENT
  SET pystatuswork  ='Cancelled',
    cancellationdate='31-JAN-14'
  WHERE pyid        =c1.pyid;
  --Begin insert into History
  --Select Operator name and ID

  SELECT skill
  INTO skill
  FROM operator_map_skill
  WHERE pyuseridentifier=c1.pxcreateoperator
  AND rownum            =1;
  INSERT
  INTO DIMS_DOC_HIST
    (
      DIMS_DOC_ID,
      DOC_CHG_USR,
      DOC_CHG_DT,
      DOC_NEW_STS,
      DOC_CHG_CMNT,
      CRE_TS,
      ROLE,
      RSN_DESC,
      TARGETROLE,
      DOC_CHG_USR_ID,
      DOC_ASG_USR_ID,
      DOC_ASG_USR,
      PREVSTATUS,
      PREVSTATUSDT,
      ASSIGNEDTODT,
      TODISPLAY,
      ACTIVITY_NAME
    )
    VALUES
    (
      c1.pyid,
      'DIMS',
      systimestamp,
      'Cancelled',
      'Cancelled due to corruption',
      '31-JAN-14',
      skill,
      NULL,
      skill,
      c1.pxcreateoperator,
      c1.pxcreateoperator,
      c1.pxcreateopname,
      'Submitted',
      NULL,
      systimestamp,
      'Y',
      'Updation through Script'
    );

  dbms_output.put_line
  (
    'Document ID= '||c1.pyid
  )
  ;
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO temp_count
  FROM PC_ASSIGN_WORKBASKET
  WHERE pxrefobjectinsname=c1.pyid;
  IF(temp_count          IS NOT NULL) THEN
    DELETE FROM PC_ASSIGN_WORKBASKET WHERE pxrefobjectinsname=c1.pyid;
  ELSE
    DELETE FROM PC_ASSIGN_WORKLIST WHERE pxrefobjectinsname=c1.pyid;
  END IF;
  COMMIT;
END;
END LOOP;
 CLOSE c1;

END;
```

Comment: Hi, I see that `c1.pyid` is used a bunch of times in your procedure. On which line exactly the error occurs (e.g. use `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS`)? BTW, could you please remove all the commented code in your question? It will be easier to read & understand.

Comment: the error is for all the c1.pyid. the table dims_doc_master has a column name pyid, so ideally the cursor should pick it up from there. I have removed the commented code.

Comment: You should be getting `PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'C1'` from that. Strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem confusing cursor and fetched row.

In your current procedure: you open a cursor, do a loop (which looks to be endless since there is no `EXIT` statement), and after the loop you close the cursor (but it looks it will never happen)

To fetch results from a cursor, do the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...
  ...
  c1 REF_CUR; 
  ddm_record dims_doc_master%rowtype; 
BEGIN 
  ...
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP 
     FETCH c1 INTO ddm_record; 
     EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
     ...
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Document ID= ' || ddm_record.pyid); -- not c1.pyid 
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
END; 
/
```

Inspired from examples here: http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-explicit-cursors.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding the flag in your where clause:

```
open c1 FOR 
SELECT *
FROM dims_doc_master
WHERE (i_flag='1' AND 
      (concat_prod_id      IS NULL
    OR documenttypeid      IS NULL
   AND (pystatuswork       = temp_status))
OR (i_flag<>'1' AND
      (documentimageid IS NULL
   AND p8id               IS NULL)
   AND (pystatuswork       = temp_status));
```

The logic can probably be simplified but logically that would work.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but it gives me an error after  c1 REF_CUR; saying encountered symbol "FOR" when expecting something else